# Java Heap Space error In Pentaho

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory, pentaho

I am using pentaho pdi version 4.1. I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error. My input is salesforce step and it would have more than 40000 rows. I tried setting `-Xmx` JVM option [in both spoon and kitchen] from `512M` to `1048M`. I got the same failure again.

Comment: Hope you restarted spoon after changing the value. Try changing it to higher value. Cos I have encountered such a thing which fixed after increasing to 2048M.

Comment: I did this and even increased to 4096M..still getting the same error

Comment: Did you try to change the commit rows value ?

Comment: Try to increase the memory as much as possible according to available RAM. Could be the app is heavy or there are memory leaks... Or check the logs to see if actualy applied the -Xmx that you gave ...and any other errors in logs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Java options might help diagnose your problem:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
```

The `UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` options logs the garbage collection actions so that you can see what happens before your out of memory error. I use the following options to help make garbage collection run better for my Java server:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:ParGCCardsPerStrideChunk=4096
```